# How do you set the axes on a histogram and swap the x and y axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, bin

I have a dataset where I want to plot a histogram of the number of measurements at each depth. I want to plot a histogram of each the frequency of measurements in the depth column. I want to bin the data into 5m chuncks starting at 0m, going up to 155m. This code, gets me a histogram, which looks a reasonable shape, but the values seem wrong, and I can't quite get it to start at 0. In addition, I would like to be able to swap the x-axis and y-axis, so that depth is on the y-axis, and frequency, is on the x-axis.

```
    import numpy as np
    import datetime as dt
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import glob


    #The data is read in, and then formatted so that an array Dout (based on depth) is created. This is done since multiple files will be read into the code, and so I can create the histogram for all the files I have up until this point.

    Dout = np.array(depthout)


    bins = np.linspace(0, 130, num=13) #, endpoint=True, retstep=False)


    plt.hist(Dout, bins)
    plt.xlabel('Depth / m')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.show()


    # the end
```

The data is in this format:

```
TagID    ProfileNo   ProfileDirn     DateTime    Lat     Lon     Depth   Temperature
```

Comment: I expected quite a different block of code when i clicked on the question after i read the title. Maybe you can post a minimal example without all that data-managing, which fits better to the title. For a horizontal barplot, check the barh_demo from the matplotlib gallery: http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

Comment: this sounds like a perfect job for pandas package.   got your code in dataframe with pd.read_clipboard().  Then df.Temperature.hist()  gives you histrogram.  got lots of slice options to do what you want to do with very little code.

Comment: Would that work with multiple files? I've never used pandas before sorry.

Comment: @Nras is that better? That link provided the necessary binning info! Thanks! However, the frequency is still definitely wrong...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the `orientation` kwarg of `hist` ([Docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist)).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.random.randn(1500)
bins = np.linspace(-5, 5, 25, endpoint=True)

ax.hist(data, bins, orientation='horizontal')
ax.set_ylim([-5, 5])
plt.show()
```

[image]